# How to change App Engine's Over Quota page?

Tags: google-app-engine, quota

Is there anyway to do this? Can I customize the AppEngine's "Over Quota" page? How?

Thanks BTW.

P.S. I mostly build python webapps, never used GAE Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom HTML error page which app engine will serve for you when you are over quota.  Check out the [Custom Error Responses](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses) documentation.